# WPF&MVVM: Ввод данных во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Если я правильно понял, то согласно концепции `MVVM`, данные должны либо храниться в модели, либо с помощью модели браться и обрабатываться из внешнего источника (например, базы данных). [В данном уроке](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.2.php) по паттерну `MVVM` для приложений `WPF` данные введены почему-то не в `Model`, а во `ViewModel`:

```
public ApplicationViewModel() {
    Phones = new ObservableCollection<Phone> {
        new Phone {Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price =60000 },
        new Phone {Title="Elite x3", Company="HP", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Mi5S", Company="Xiaomi", Price=35000 }
    };
}
```

Плохой пример, или я что-то неправильно понял насчёт концепции хранения данных в `MVVM`?

Comment: Концепция хранения данных ортогональна MVVM. Это всего лишь один из вариантов разделения приложения на логические части.

Вид (View) - визуальная часть, отвечает за отображение.
Вью-модель (ViewModel) - отвечает за предоставление данных для отображение. 
Модель (Model) - все остальное. Такое вот широкое понятие. Вьюмодель пользуется моделью как нижележащим слоем.

Comment: @vitidev, Благодарю Вас за ответ! Скажите пожалуйста, а если я хочу считать данные из внешнего источника (например, из файла), то в каком элементе шаблона `MVVM` это лучше сделать?

Comment: Очевидно в модели. Вьюмодель лишь может попросить у модели предоставить ей данные для отображения, но откуда эти данные берутся - не ее дело. И уж точно не в виде это делать.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за ответ ещё раз!

Comment: В том примере просто ради упрощения не стали заводить модель с БД или другим источником данных. В реальных задачах модель обычно уже имеется или диктуется ТЗ. Модель должна быть самодостаточна, она может, например, быть выгружена в отдельную библиотеку и подключена к консольному приложению