# WPF: Можно ли реализовать автозаполнение в ComboBox с ComboBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В ходе обучения разработке приложений `WPF` экспериментально установил, что функция автозаполнения в `ComboBox` работает только когда внутри - цельный `TextBlock` (поправьте, если это не так). Пример:

```
<ComboBox Name="People" IsEditable="True">
    <TextBlock>Andrew Invanov</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Sergey Petrov</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Valadimir Sidorov</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Nikolay Kuznetsow</TextBlock>
</ComboBox>
```

Теперь предположим, что мы хотим включить в список не только имя и фамилию, но и какой-нибудь ID, при этом хотим, чтобы автозаполнение работало как при вводе первых цифер ID, так и при вводе первых букв имени. Можно ли это реализовать, и если да, то как? Только программно?

ID и имя разнесены в разные `TextBlock` затем, чтобы к ID и имени можно было применить разные стили.

```
<ComboBox Name="People" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Andrew Invanov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Sergey Petrov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Valadimir Sidorov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Nikolay Kuznetsow</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

---

*Если для ответа на данный вопрос Вам нужно поэкспериментировать с кодом, то в целях экономии Вашего времени я подготовил проект для Visual Studio с начальной разметкой `ComboBox`.*

*[Ссылка на Яндекс Диск](https://yadi.sk/d/tSF8QBNR3NYGXY) (возможно станет недоступна после получения ответа на вопрос).*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66752/discussion-on-question-by-gurebu-bokofu-wpf----).

Answer (score 2):

Разметка

```
<ComboBox Name="boxOrig" IsEditable="True" Height="30" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0" Text="{Binding id}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Список с элементами

```
class Lol
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id + " " + name;
    }
}

List<Lol> list = new List<Lol>()
{
    new Lol()
    {
        id = 1,
        name = "Andrew Invanov"
    },
    new Lol()
    {
        id = 2,
        name = "Sergey Petrov"
    },
    new Lol()
    {
        id = 3,
        name = "Valadimir Sidorov"
    },
    new Lol()
    {
        id = 4,
        name = "Nikolay Kuznetsow"
    }
};
```

Фильтрация

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    boxOrig.ItemsSource = list;
    boxOrig.DropDownOpened+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        filter(boxOrig.Text, true);
    };
    boxOrig.PreviewTextInput += (sender, args) =>
    {
        string text = boxOrig.Text + args.Text;
        filter(text);
    };
}

private void filter(string text, bool drop=false)
{
    var filtered = list
        .Where(x => x.id.ToString().StartsWith(text, true) || x.name.StartsWith(text, true))
        .ToList();
    if (filtered.Count > 0 )
    {
        boxOrig.ItemsSource = filtered;
        boxOrig.SelectedItem = filtered.First();
        if (!drop) //Обновление текста в ComboBox
        {
            boxOrig.IsEditable = false;
            boxOrig.IsEditable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Поясните, пожалуйста, некоторые основы. Что это за объявление `new Lol(){Id = 1564, Name = "Andrew Invanov"           }`? Обычно класс экземпляр класса создаётся как `new Person(1564, "Andrew Invanov")`.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu это инициализатор объекта.

Comment: а чем такой подход отличается от обычной инициализации типа `new Person(1564, "Andrew Invanov")`? (Дальше, соответственно, данные идут в конструктор).

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Я не создавал конструктор. Вы приводили пример инициализатора в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727291/wpfmvvm-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE-viewmodel) вопросе

Comment: хорошо, ещё раз благодарю Вас за потраченное время! Буду дальше разбираться и дорабатывать Ваш код, так как поведение фильтра пока не такое же, как у фильтра по умолчанию. Во-первых, при вводе первой буквы или цифры сразу же первое совпадение выводится в поле и на этом ввод перкращается, а требуемое поведение - в окне пока остаётся введённая пользователем буква, при этом раскрывается список с отфильтрованными значениями. Но всё равно благодарю Вас за основу для кода!

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Это нельзя сделать, так как для этого нужно изменять код компонента.

Comment: понятно, буду собирать больше информации и решений по данной теме.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Я ошибся, [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33427773/4854931) [способ фильтрации](https://gist.github.com/mariodivece/0bbade976aea8d416d52#gistcomment-1867349) с отображеним dropdown, по-моему, это лучше автозаполнения.

Comment: Условие фильтрации можно переделать https://i.imgur.com/upHI0Vx.png

Comment: отлично, благодарю Вас за поиск! Мне понадобится время, чтобы внедрить решение и поэкспериментировать. Я напишу снова, если возникнут проблемы.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu что долгого внедрить? Надо просто выполнить просто метод расширения для `ComboBox`.

Comment: Да вот, пытаюсь понять, как данный метод применять в рамках MVVM. Так как `ViewModel` особо в отображение вмешиваться не должно, остаётся только `View` - класс окна для добавления в него `MakeComboBoxSearchable()`. Далее, насколько я понял, нужно в этом же классе всем желаемым комбобоксам присвоить данное поведение через `MakeComboBoxSearchable()`.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu каким кнопкам? Комбобоксам.

Comment: Пордон, ошибся в названии элемента.

Answer (score 1):

[Нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33427773/4854931) метод [расширения](https://gist.github.com/mariodivece/0bbade976aea8d416d52#gistcomment-1867349) для отображения `Dropdown'a` при изменении текста в `ComboBox` и возможности фильтрации не только по началу текста.

```
boxOrig.MakeComboBoxSearchable(
    searchText => (item =>
    {
        Lol lolItem = (Lol) item;
        return lolItem.id.ToString().StartsWith(searchText, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
            || lolItem.name.StartsWith(searchText, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    })
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс с расширением

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void MakeComboBoxSearchable(this ComboBox targetComboBox,
        Func<string, Predicate<object>> itemsFilter = null)
    {
        if (itemsFilter == null)
        {
            itemsFilter = searchText => (item =>
                    item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
        }
        targetComboBox.Loaded += (sender, e) => TargetComboBox_Loaded(sender, e, itemsFilter);
    }

    private static void TargetComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e,
        Func<string, Predicate<object>> itemsFilter)
    {
        var targetComboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        var targetTextBox = targetComboBox?.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", targetComboBox) as TextBox;

        if (targetTextBox == null) return;

        targetComboBox.Tag = "TextInput";
        targetComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit = true;
        targetComboBox.IsEditable = true;
        targetComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;

        targetTextBox.TextChanged += (o, args) =>
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox) o;

            var searchText = textBox.Text;

            if (targetComboBox.Tag.ToString() == "Selection")
            {
                targetComboBox.Tag = "TextInput";
                targetComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (targetComboBox.SelectionBoxItem != null)
                {
                    targetComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
                    targetTextBox.Text = searchText;
                    textBox.CaretIndex = targetTextBox.Text.Length;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    targetComboBox.Items.Filter = item => true;
                    targetComboBox.SelectedItem = default(object);
                }
                else
                    targetComboBox.Items.Filter = itemsFilter(searchText);

                Keyboard.ClearFocus();
                Keyboard.Focus(targetTextBox);
                targetComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                targetTextBox.SelectionStart = targetTextBox.Text.Length;
            }
        };


        targetComboBox.SelectionChanged += (o, args) =>
        {
            var comboBox = o as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox?.SelectedItem == null) return;
            comboBox.Tag = "Selection";
        };
    }
}
```

Разметка

```
<ComboBox Name="boxOrig" Height="30" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0" Text="{Binding id}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Список с элементами

```
class Lol
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id + " " + name;
    }
}

List<Lol> list = new List<Lol>()
{
    new Lol() {id = 1, name = "Andrew Invanov"},
    new Lol() {id = 2, name = "Sergey Petrov"},
    new Lol() {id = 3, name = "Valadimir Sidorov"},
    new Lol() {id = 4, name = "Nikolay Kuznetsow"},
    new Lol() {id = 5, name = "Nikolay Petrov"}
};
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за Ваши изыскания!

Comment: @GurebuBokofu это то, что вы хотели?

Comment: я отвечу, когда попробую это на реальном проекте.