# WPF: Корректное отображение выбранного пункта в ComboBox с ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

Допустим, у нас в WPF-проекте имеется `ComboBox` и вложенными `ComboBoxItem`:

```
<ComboBox Name="People" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Andrew Invanov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Sergey Petrov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Valadimir Sidorov</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="0 0 10 0">3845</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Nikolay Kuznetsow</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Если не вмешиваться в программную часть и выбрать в списке какой-нибудь пункт, то отобразится ссылка на объект `ComboBoxItem`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит и что надо сделать, чтобы при выборе пункта в `ComboBox` отображалось что надо?

Comment: Так происходит потому что у вас включена возможность редактирования `ComboBox`. Соответственно он не знает как именно нужно редактировать сложные объекты.  Читайте здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the

Comment: лучше не заполнять `ComboBox` подобным образом

Comment: Что вы понимаете под отображалось "как надо"?

Comment: @Foggy Finder, "как надо", значит что при выборе опции в поле ввода было не `System.Windows.Controld.ComboBoxItem`, а текстовое содержимое, например `3845 Nikolay Kuznetsow` (помимо текста я также видел примеры с картинками).

Comment: для этого определяют шаблон для элемента списка (или в простых случаях переопределяют .ToString())

Comment: но меня более интересуют каким образом вы хотите редактировать выбранный элемент?

Comment: @Foggy Finder, конкретно в моей задаче, редактировать - никак. Ввод нужен исключительно для того, чтобы с помощью фильтрации быстрее нужный пункт, когда список очень длинный, а редактирование с помощью `ComboBox` я на данный момент не рассматриваю.

Comment: @Foggy Finder, [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727700/wpf-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-combobox-%D1%81-comboboxitem/727731?noredirect=1#comment1101304_727731) мы обсуждаем данную тему, то есть фильтрацию, а в этом вопросе - корректное отображение уже выбранного пункта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66760/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-gurebu-bokofu).