# WPF&MVVM: Ввод начальных данных в Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Как это было отмечено в одном из комментариев к вопросу [Ввод данных во ViewModel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727291/wpfmvvm-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE-viewmodel), хранение данных во `ViewModel` является противоречием шаблону `MVVM`, но во всех уроках по `MVVM` для начинающих, которые я видел, в целях урощения ввод данных осуществляется именно во `ViewModel`.

В своей первый попытке получить данные из модели я взял за основу я взял [код из уроков](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php) на сайте [metanit.com](https://metanit.com/) (полный код вставлять в вопрос не буду; он доступен в [исходниках](https://yadi.sk/d/byUhfATJ3NYJos)):

**MainWindow.xaml**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Phoce.cs** (Model)

```
namespace MVVM_GetDataFromTextFileToModel_Test {
    public class Phone : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string title;
        private string company;
        private int price;

        public string Title {
            get { return title; }
            set {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        public string Company {
            get { return company; }
            set {
                company = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
        public int Price {
            get { return price; }
            set {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Наконец, ввод начальных данных осуществляется во `ViewModel`, а имеено в её конструкторе:

```
public ApplicationViewModel() {
    Phones = new ObservableCollection<Phone>
    {
        new Phone {Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price =60000 },
        new Phone {Title="Elite x3", Company="HP", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Mi5S", Company="Xiaomi", Price=35000 }
    };
}
```

Я рассуждал так, что если для `XAML` нужна `ObservableCollection`, значит мы должны создать её внутри модели. Но получается, что для объявления данной переменной надо сослаться на тот же класс, в котором мы переменную и объявляем:

```
public ObservableCollection<Phone> phones;
```

Пока IDE не даёт никаких предупреждений. Далее я не понял:

- Как следует описать `setter` в свойстве `Phones`?

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones {

      get { return phones; }
      set {

      }
  }
  ```
- Где именно внутри модели лучше ввести начальные данные?
- Как лучше при создании экземпляра класса `Phone` во `ViewModel` организовать получение коллекции данных?

---

[Ссылка на исходники](https://yadi.sk/d/byUhfATJ3NYJos) (Яндекс Диск; возможно станет недоступна после получения ответа на вопрос)

---

### Обновление

Добавил в модель метод, возвращающий `ObservableCollection<Phone>` и вызвал его в конструкторе `ApplicationViewModel`. Приложение собирается, но данных никаких не выводит.

**Phone.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<Phone> getPhones() {
    return new ObservableCollection<Phone> {
        new Phone { Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price =60000 },
        new Phone {Title="Elite x3", Company="HP", Price=56000 },
        new Phone {Title="Mi5S", Company="Xiaomi", Price=35000 }
    };
}
```

**ApplicationViewModel**

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones;

    // ... 

    public ApplicationViewModel() {
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        Phones = phone.getPhones();
    }    
    // ...    
}
```

Кстати, мне не совсем понятна конструкция в `ApplicationViewModel` при объявлении полей класса, которая была до этого:

```
public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
```

Мы объявляем коллекцию, но при этом объявляем методы `get` и `set`? Если так всё и оставить, то мой исправленный код не скомплируется, поэтому я оставил только `public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones;`.

Comment: 1. Никак, он тут не нужен. 2. Сделайте метод GetPhones в модели. Тому кому нужны эти данные создаёт экземпляр модельного класса и вызывает его метод, который возвращает нужные данные. Это может быть как конструктор VM, так и команда, например

Comment: Почему бы не сделать наследование `Model` от `DependencyObject` ? и писать нормальные поля с помощью простейшего фрагмента кода -
`propdp` ?

Comment: @Birdy, а как тогда быть с наследованием `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Без него не будет работать `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Андрей, сделал, как Вы сказали. Компилируется, но данных не выводит. Вероятно, причина в том, что я не понял смысла `public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }`, что было до этого. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Стоп. Привязка работает только со свойствами (не полями!), поэтому объявите так: `public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Phone>();`

Comment: Дальше, так как у нас нет сеттера, то мы не должны перезаписывать саму коллекцию, мы должны только добавлять/удалять из нее элементы (Add/Remove). Ваша модель не обязана возвращать `ObservableCollection`, обычно она вообще возвращает IEnumerable (или, может быть, IQueryable если она работает с БД)

Comment: Ну и чисто семантически, вы создаете телефон, который вам возвращает коллекцию телефонов? Ну сделайте вы класс PhoneRepository, который уже будет нести ответственность за хранение/выдачу телефонов по отдельности или скопом, а сам телефон не должен за отвечать - это ведь простой сущностный класс...

Comment: @Андрей, а что тогда следует вернуть? Как видите на данный момент я пока что объявляю данные напрямую в модели, но это я начал с простого, следующим этапом буду получать данные из внешних файлов.

Comment: Если вы всё же хотите перезаписывать `ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones` целиком, тогда вам нужно на нее также навесить `PropertyChanged`, т.е. вам тогда потребуется приватное поддерживающее поле как у вас было до этого

Comment: @Андрей, если создать `PhoneRepository`, то тогда по концепции `MVVM` оба класса `PhoneRepository` и `Phone` будут считаться моделью, или `PhoneRepository` - это уже нечто вроде контроллера для работы данными будет?

Comment: Да, конечно, оба класса, кто сказал, что нужно ограничиться одним, обычно модель - это целая библиотека, которая много что умеет

Comment: @Андрей, отлично! Благодаря Вам, я справился! С Вашего разрешения, выложy рабочее решение в ответ, чтобы другие могли им пользоваться. Или сами хотите написать ответ, чтобы очки репутации получить?

Comment: Пишите сами, мне лениво сочинять. Заодно и посмотрим что вы там сделали

Comment: @Андрей, Хорошо! Но учитывая, сколько Вы отвечаете на вопросы, лень Вам явно не свойственна :)

Answer (score 1):

- `Phone.cs` без изменений - это сущностной класс.
- В `PhoneRepository.cs` находятся данные телефонов (на следующем этапе обучения их нужно будет взять из внешних источников, например БД). Метод `getAllPhones()` возвращает все телефоны в виде `ObservableCollection<Phone>`; метод `getPhoneByName(string phoneName)` возвращает телефон по имени (я не переименовал свойство `Title`, когда брал за основу код с урока на metanit.com).

  ```
  class PhoneRepository {

      private ObservableCollection<Phone> phones = new ObservableCollection<Phone> {
          new Phone {Title="iPhone7", Company="Apple", Price=56000 },
          new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price =60000 },
          new Phone {Title="Elite x3", Company="HP", Price=56000 },
          new Phone {Title="Mi5S", Company="Xiaomi", Price=35000 }
      };


      public ObservableCollection<Phone> GetAllPhones(){
          return phones;
      }

      public Phone GetPhoneByName(string phoneName) {
          foreach (var phone in phones) {
              if (phone.Title == phoneName) {
                  return phone;
              }
          }
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- В `ApplicationViewModel` необходимо изменить объявление Phones, потому что как сказал @Андрей в комментариях, привязка работает только со свойствами, но не полями.

  ```
  public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

      public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; } =
          new ObservableCollection<Phone>();

      // ...

      public ApplicationViewModel() {
          PhoneRepository phoneRepository = new PhoneRepository();
          Phones = phoneRepository.GetAllPhones();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: В C# принято публичные свойства/методы именовать в PascalCase, а не в camelCase и открывающую фигурную скобку писать на новой строке. Но это так, к делу не относящееся... :)

Comment: @Андрей, Это я со времён программирования под Андроид привык все имена методов с маленькой буквы писать:) Но со временем привыкну и к правилам C#. А вот фигурная скобка с новой строчки, если честно, сильно мозолит глаза...

Comment: В java свои гайдлайны, в шарпе - свои. Но в общем это к делу не относится и вы должны придерживаться стиля, который принят в команде. С другой стороны читать код привычно оформленный - легче

Comment: А Вы когда читаете мой код, то насколько фигурная скобка, идущая на той же строчке, что и имя класса или метода, у Вас как у эксперта по C# вызывает дискомфорт?

Comment: Я не эксперт, но для меня лично это вызывает больше дискомфорта, чем ваш camelCase, но меньше, чем, например, отсутствие отступов. Где-то на 5 по 10-бальной шкале :D

Comment: @Андрей, пытался сделать отступы, но редактор тупит - не отличает код от обычного текста.

Comment: Просто нужно больше пробелов :)

Comment: Спасибо за редактирование!